# How to reset user ID for Registered Users

Tags: firebase, registration

With Email & Password Authentication, how can we turn off auto-incrementation, or at least reset the id back to 0?

Comment: That's not currently a feature AFAIK. support@firebase.com might be able to help you.

Comment: Found an easy solution:  simply delete your app (by going to the main dashboard, then within your app section click on the gear icon, and select "delete app").  Be sure to ensure your data is saved first!

Comment: And then re-create it and import the data?